# Android Eclipse Split for newline

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my application android I've inserted :

```
Log.i("myApp1", response.toString());
```

This is the output of LogCat in Eclipse for response.toString:

```
04-08 20:54:21.674: I/myApp1(9930): 23/03/2014<br />Pics 1<br /><br /><br />09/03/2014<br />Pics 2<br /><br /><br />
```

How do I get this output in layout android? I need tried to split for **< br />** without success...

```
23/03/2014

Pics 1

09/03/2014

Pics 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<br />` which is HTML code use `\n` in your code.

```
String editedResponse = response.replaceAll("<br />", "\n");
Log.i("MyApp1", editedResponse);
```

If you want to display this string in a TextView be sure you set the android:lines to 2 or greater.

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/txtTitlevalue"
   android:text="Line1: \n-Line2\n-Line3"
   android:layout_width="54dip"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:lines="2"
   android:textSize="11px" />
```

Comment: Okay thank you. Now I've this output `23/03/2014` how to for set textView with this value in layout android?

Comment: Use the android:lines="2" parameter in your TextView and in your code just say textTitleValue.setText(editedResponse);